# Using async and await with export const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I can't make this work...it's says: await is a reserved word. Yes, of course it is...and I'd like to use it :)

What's wrong ?

```
export const loginWithToken = async () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: SESSION_LOGIN_IN_PROGRESS, payload: true})
    let storedData = await ReadFromLocalDB('user')
    console.log(storedData)
    if (!storedData) {
        invalidToken(null, dispatch)
    }
    else {
        storedData = JSON.parse(storedData)
        SessionLoginWithToken(storedData.session.token).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            loginSuccessfully(res, dispatch, true)
        })
    }
  }
}
```

My `ReadFromLocalDB` function looks like this:

```
export const ReadFromLocalDB = async (key) => {
   return AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
}
```

It returns a promise

Comment: Change it from an 'export const' (ie. use 'let'); is that relevant to the problem/issue? If not, remove it from the title. Remember to eliminate non-relevant information and reduce problem scope.

Comment: `return dispatch => {...}` needs to also be `async` I believe.  Right now, only the top level function is async, not the nested one.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`return dispatch => {...}` needs to also be `async` I believe. Right now, only the top level function is `async`, not the nested one.

```js
// This function is async
export const loginWithToken = async () => {
  // This one is not though which means it can't use await inside
  // return dispatch => {

  // Instead it should likely be:
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: SESSION_LOGIN_IN_PROGRESS, payload: true})
    let storedData = await ReadFromLocalDB('user')
    console.log(storedData)
    if (!storedData) {
        invalidToken(null, dispatch)
    }
    else {
        storedData = JSON.parse(storedData)
        SessionLoginWithToken(storedData.session.token).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            loginSuccessfully(res, dispatch, true)
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, Zero ! Yes, you are right ! that's the reason !

Answer (score 9):

With export and import we are suggested to follow the model:

To define and export a function in the file myFile.js:

```
export const request = async (arg1, arg2) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.com/values/?arg1=' + arg1 + '&arg2=' arg2);
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log('We have the error', e);
  }
}
```

To import and apply the function:

```
import {request} from './myFile'

request(arg1, arg2);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's because the function you return (`dispatch => {...}`) is not an async function, so you can't use `await` in it. You would need to do something like `return async dispatch => {...}`

Comment: Exactly -- just because that inner function is inside an `async` function doesn't mean you can use `await` in it. The function `await` is used in, itself, must be `async`.