# Export a constant fetched from an async function in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, constants, token

I'm quite new to Ruby and facing this problem.

I want to define a constant that I can use anywhere in my code.  It is a token(string) to access an API.

Thing is, I get it from an async function.

```
const fetchApiToken = async () => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: API_URL + 'v2/auth/token/',
      data: {
        api_key:  API_KEY
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' //was getting 406 without this
      }
    }

    axios(config)
    .then(resp => resp.data.token)
    .then(function(token){
      resolve(token);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err.message);
    });
  })
}
```

Using this would work but would export a promise :

```
    export const USER_TOKEN = fetchApiToken(); //is a promise
```

Which is not handy since I will need to use `USER_TOKEN.then((function(token){})` everywhere in my code.

I've searched the web (like [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804207/using-async-and-await-with-export-const/50804268)), but cannot find a good way to handle this.

How would you do ?
I just need to export the token, which is a string; but i'm getting it from an async function.

Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning asynchronous data then exporting it synchronously in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52827300/returning-asynchronous-data-then-exporting-it-synchronously-in-node-js)

Comment: Since the key is retrieved asynchronously, there's no way around having `.then`s *somewhere*. Best approach I've found is to identify the *entry point* of the whole script, and have it call `fetchApiToken`, and only call the rest of the script inside the `.then` - that way there's only one `.then` needed, pass the token as a parameter as needed